# in YAML with python - how can I define the types in my map?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm stumped. here's what I want to structure my docs as:

```
release: JULY
files:
    # files
    /foo/config.py:       1.6
    /bar/dao.py:                1.19
```

I then want to return files based on the release given in python. That part's easy, but it's returning the Values as floats, which poses a problem. I'd like to force them to strings without preprocessing. (I don't want to open a file, loop through the versions, and prepend !!python/str to each entry)

I assume that tags are the way to do this, but I can't make heads or tails of the documentation in terms of how/where I can define a tag.

Any pointers?

Comment: Adding quotes around the numbers is slightly easier. You propably won't be able to make it work magically, at least not across YAML parsers - IIRC, the YAML spec demands that `\d+\.\d+` is treated as float.

Comment: can't I create a definition like an XML schema?

Comment: There are projects that try to provide such things, e.g. [Kwalify](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwalify/), but I don't know if they provide parsing including type enforcements or just check if a standard parser parses it into an object that meets the schema.

Comment: Use Kwalify to force your users to use strings, quoting as necessary? Or use only three-digits version numbers à la [semver](http://semver.org/), which will parse as strings.

Comment: I ended up biting the bullet and writing a preprocessor to prepend !!python/str to the values in the map. Not ideal but workable.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to specify the type for a string, if you want to dump the `float` values as strings, just call `str()` on them first:

```
>>> d = {'release': 'JULY', 'files': {'/path/file': str(1.6), '/path/file2': str(1.9)}}

>>> print yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=False)
files:
  /path/file: '1.6'
  /path/file2: '1.9'
release: JULY
```

If you want to serialize/deserialize custom objects, you can do that to some extent, just by defining `__repr__` in your class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.x)

>>> f = Foo(0)
>>> foo = yaml.dump(f)
>>> yaml.load(foo)
<<< Foo(0)
```

Comment: maybe I'm using YAML wrong. My goal was to give users a structure, and parse said document to grab lists to further operate on. 
This and my other research are implying that the end user has to know the structure format for YAML which breaks my use case terribly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is subclass `Loader` and call `add_path_resolver`, something like this:

```
class MyLoader(yaml.Loader):
    pass
MyLoader.add_path_resolver(SOME_TAG, SOME_PATH, str)

f = open('foo.yaml')
the_data = yaml.load(f, Loader=MyLoader)
```

But I can't find any documentation on `add_path_resolver` and what the `SOME_TAG` and `SOME_PATH` should be.

Comment: Won't work, add_path_resolver is only enabled for non-scalars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875579/parse-yaml-and-assume-a-certain-path-is-always-a-string/4151152#4151152